# Unable to run USB

Tags: usb, live-usb

I was trying to format bootable USB and I am getting the following error:

[image]

Please help me to format my USB.

Comment: ISO9660 is a format for CD-Rom and other optical storage, not for USB.

Comment: That's the error I'm getting when I insert my USB drive

Comment: Anyway it's not a very serious error as you want to format the USB, which you can't do as long as the drive is mounted. Before you go on to format the drive `/dev/sdb1` however, make doubly sure that it is your USB drive that is going to be formatted. Use `df` and/or `blkid` to find out.

Comment: I tried to format through " applications->disk->format and I got synchronization error. Now the USB option is not showing in my system and I tried you commands also error : " bash: /Dev/sdb1: permission denied"

Comment: Can you format it with Gparted?

Comment: Some boot drive makers such as Startup Disk Creator clone the OS as a ISO9660 file system. This FS can be undone using **mkusb** - "Restore to a standard storage device" or **GParted** - "Device/Create Partition Table".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? https://fossbytes.com/create-bootable-usb-media-from-iso-ubuntu/

But according to the error message it seams to be, that your usb drive, respectivly the file system is broken.

Try the following command: `sudo jfs_fsck /dev/sdb1`
Thats all I know, maybe it helps. If not  you should consider buying a new USB drive. (or hope someone with more experience emerges)

Comment: I tried command which you given and not working in my system, are you recommending to buy a new pen drive?